# How do you add an expire header to a static website hosted with AWS Amplify?

Tags: page-speed, http-headers

My website's speed test with Pingdom got an F grade for Expire Headers. What would be the best way to add them to a basic HTML website? I have searched for ways to add them, but none of them involve a basic website. All the searches involve some sort of CMS.

Answer (score 1):

I believe these are the docs: [Custom headers - AWS Amplify](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/custom-headers.html#setting-custom-headers). Looks like there are two ways: either through the management console or by creating a `customHttp.yml` file.

If you end up searching more as you start adding custom headers, I highly suggest searching on Stack Overflow, because it looks like there are [a few answered questions on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Baws-amplify%5D+custom+headers) that might help.